# JMX Authentication - Role Based MBean Operations

Tags: java, authentication, jmx, mbeans

I have implemented `JMXAuthenticator` for JMX authentication over RMI, however I am not sure how to create roles to allow for readonly/readwrite access levels. For example, in `JMXAuthenticator.authenticate` I have my custom authentication logic and want this to determine the access role. I have tried the following but it makes no difference when performing operations in JConsole:

```
@Override
public Subject authenticate(Object credentials) {
    Subject subject = new Subject();
    JMXPrincipal p;

    //...my logic
    String accessLevel = myCustomLogic();
    if (accessLevel.equals("admin")) {
        p = new JMXPrincipal("adminrole");
    } else {
        p = new JMXPrincipal("basicrole");
    }

    subject.getPrincipals().add(p);
    return subject;
}
```

I have then created an access file, `jmxaccess.properties`, containing

```
adminuser readwrite
basicuser readonly
```

and `jmx.management.properties` which contains `com.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=PATH TO ACCESS FILE` and I run the application with `-Dcom.sun.management.config.file=PATH TO jmx.management.properties`.

However when I connect through JConsole and authenticate as a basicuser (read only access) I can access setters on the bean. I am connecting via the full `service:jmx:rmi:...` url.

So my questions are

- Do I need to annotate/do anything to the setters in my bean to specify them as visible only to admin users?
- Am I not building the `Subject` object correctly which the `JMXAuthenticator` returns?
- Any other config/setup that is missing?

Thanks

**Edit** My MBean is just a basic POJO with private fields that have public getters and setters plus one other public method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: need to implement a custom invocation handler via `InvocationHandler` interface. This intercepts server calls before they reach the beans. Inside the authenticate method you need to check the principals

```
AccessControlContext acc = AccessController.getContext();
Subject subject = Subject.getSubject(acc);
Set principals = subject.getPrincipals(JMXPrincipal.class);
if(principals != null && !principals.isEmpty()) {
    Principal principal = (Principal)principals.iterator().next();
    //your checks
}
```

I extended JMXPrincipal (one extension per access level) and assigned it to the Subject in the Authenticator above, then after retrieving the principal in the IH, I can check the type via `instanceof` and either allow the action to continue or throw a `SecurityException`.

Comment: Hi, can you share your solution on github or something like that? :)