# Is remote JMX security out-of-the-box really so basic or am I missing something?

Tags: java, security, rmi, jmx

I just spent the day building and rebuilding docker images of my app with different variations of JVM command line options `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote...`.

**So I can get JMX authentication to work which was one step forward, but then anybody in my organisation could login and execute JMX commands.**

But it seems to me that I have to rely on putting usernames and passwords in text files in my docker containers (or accessible to them) *if I want to restrict authorization to a small group of users*.

Isn't there another out-of-the-box way to monitor memory and threads and manipulate loggers or connection pools etc in production?

The official docs [Monitoring and Management Using JMX Technology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html) are not encouraging.

I thought microservices architecture might have a new approach but I can't find it on the web or on stackoverflow.

I investigated coding up a routine to launch the JMX server internally with custom authorization to use the Krb5LoginModule to access AD groups following [JMX Authentication - Role Based MBean Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192456/jmx-authentication-role-based-mbean-operations) and [Support for Kerberos Authentication/Authorization on JMX Client/Server running on Java 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532828/support-for-kerberos-authentication-authorization-on-jmx-client-server-running-o)

I even dredged up a long-since vanished Oracle blog post on the subject at the waybackmachine: [Authentication and Authorization in JMX RMI connectors](https://web.archive.org/web/20160410153013/https://blogs.oracle.com/lmalventosa/entry/jmx_authentication_authorization)

Now at the end of the day it's obvious that I have to keep it simpler than this and go with the out-of-the-box solution, but that is so primitive and looks like it hasn't been improved since Java 1.6.

Is JMX just a basic mechanism to allow EJB containers to do JMX, which of course being gargantuan EJB containers, they have their own JMX connectors that pre-authorize everything.

Isn't there something that will allow me to implement AD groups for authorization in a multi-user environment without writing my own JMX security module?

Comment: LDAP authentication seems easy enough, as long as you already have a users LDAP repository. If you want a more custom solution, I guess you would have to implement it yourself